# Problem with writing an infix macro in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to write a Clojure infix macro, but I get a compilation error which I don't understand.

It should produce function calls from the regular math expression syntax:

```
(macroexpand '(infix 3 * (2 + 1)))
;; => (* 3 (+ 2 1))
```

I tried to switch the `list` statement to a quote, but it didn't work.

The macro:

```
(defmacro functionize [macro]
  `(fn [& args#] (eval (cons '~macro args#))))

(defmacro infix
  ([n]
   (if (not (or (number? n) (fn? n)))
     `(~(apply (functionize infix) n))
     n))
  ([fir sec & res]
   (list sec (infix fir) (infix res))))
```

The error:

```
1. Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
   Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol
```

The error is for the last line, for the first call for `infix`.

Comment: Could you please update your question with example input and expected and actual output from the macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i can see at least one possible error in your code: `[fir sec & res]` should probably be `[fir sec res]`, since you need the third arg, not the list of all args. It still doesn't fix the problems in your code. The main one, is that you are overthinking it (with `eval` and stuff)

I would probably use something like this:

```
(defmacro infix [n]
  (if (list? n)
    (let [[arg1 op arg2] n]
      `(~op (infix ~arg1) (infix ~arg2)))
    n))

user> (clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(infix (1 + ((6 - (3 / 7)) * 3))))
;;=> (+ 1 (* (- 6 (/ 3 7)) 3))

user> (infix (1 + ((6 - (3 / 7)) * 3)))
;;=> 124/7
```

**UPDATE**

to omit parentheses you could update it this way:

```
(defn unwrap-arg [restargs]
  (if (= 1 (count restargs))
    (first restargs)
    restargs))

(defmacro infix [n]
  (if (list? n)
    (let [[arg1 op & arg2] n]
      `(~op (infix ~arg1) (infix ~(unwrap-arg arg2))))
    n))

user> (clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(infix (1 + 2 + (10 - (4 / 10)) + (4 * 5))))
;;=> (+ 1 (+ 2 (+ (- 10 (/ 4 10)) (* 4 5))))

user> (infix (1 + 2 + (10 - (4 / 10)) + (4 * 5)))
;;=> 163/5
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I used a rest argument because I wanted the macro to make it easier to write long mathematical expressions without many parentheses, while still keeping the option to use them like in math (like the example call I wrote, or (infix 1 + 2 + 3)). How could I do that?